# Write a bit-by-bit file in java

Tags: java, fileinputstream, bit

I'm trying to write a bit-by-bit file in java, but I do not know how to do it, I've tried with FileOutputStream, but the problem is that I need to specify what bit is written in the file in each case (0 or 1), bit by bit. ..
If someone can help me and guide me a little, I would really appreciate it!

Ok I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220917/is-it-possible-to-read-write-bits-from-a-file-using-java?noredirect=1&lq=1) and now I understand that in java it is not possible to write bit by bit.
What I'm trying to do is implement the Hoffman algorithm, but if I can not write bit by bit, I do not understand how to do the compression. For example, in a .txt file a character weighs a byte and when it is changed by the code of the Huffman tree, its weight increases, since it takes me every 0 or 1, as characters.
Sorry if my question is very silly, but I'm pretty newbie.

Comment: There's no such thing. You need to aggregate 8 bits and then write a byte. A File*Input*Stream is not helpful for writing.

Comment: From your updated comment, your question is essentially "How do I write some number of bits to a file that isn't a multiple of 8, given that I have to write byte at a time". And the answer is essentially that you "organise things in some way" so that even if you have to write 'useless' bits at the end of the file/data to make things up to a multiple of 8, you know to ignore those leftover bits (e.g, store the decompressed length of the data, encode a special 'end of stream' marker as part of your encoded data...)

Comment: Incidentally, if you simply want to compress data using the Huffman algorithm in Java without writing your own implementation, see the Deflater and DeflaterOutputStream classes (and the corresponding 'HUFFMAN_ONLY' strategy that can be configured).

Comment: Thanks for answering.
The implementation of Huffman is to make it complete, without using Deflater class.
So, since the minimum I can write is a byte ... How can I do to specify 0 or 1 in each bit of that byte?

Comment: The BitSet works pretty well.  You can write a class that accumulates groups of bits into a byte array then writes them all out at once.  I did this for video packets, took a little work but not really hard.  Also the shift operators work, but you have to ensure that you "roll" to the next char/byte/int/long/whatever you use when the current one fills up.